# Migrating from vtiger 5.3.0 to 5.4.0 failure

Tags: vtiger

Trying to migrate from vtiger 5.3.0 to 5.4.0 and getting this error when I navigate to the patch folder in a browser:

Warning: require_once(include/logging.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \vtigercrm-5.3.0\apache\htdocs\vtigerCRM\upgrade\include\database\PearDatabase.php on line 1

Using google I've found people with this error with migrating different versions, though not these versions, and no forum topics with an actual answer to this problem, am I the only one!?

I put the patch in '\vtigercrm-5.3.0\apache\htdocs\vtigerCRM' then navigated to it and got this error, any ideas!?

Answer (score 2):

Please Don`t use the patch if you want complate migration just follow this links.

[Click here](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtiger_CRM_5.4_Migration)

Answer (score 2):

if you want complete information just follow this links.

https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtiger_CRM_5.4_Migration

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a little late to say anything, however, I'm getting the same error. I think, from what I've read, that the problem may be the installation directory. I see you've moved everything to "upgrade". Maybe the problem was there.

Answer (score -2):

The migration method that you are attempting is not to be done using a patch. What you are attempting to do will only work with a complete application package.